# .Net Wizard user inputs being overwritten

Tags: c#, .net, postback, wizard

I have been searching quite a bit, but unable to find something that addresses the issue I am seeing. I am sure I am missing something simple, but I have been fighting it too long, and really need to figure out what is going on. I have an existing (working) user control that I am rebuilding. It is a multi-step wizard, with each step being a type of "form" created from tables. I have successfully converted 3 of the 4 steps to divs to make them dynamic (using Bootstrap 3), but this one step, step 2, is not working like the rest. The user's input is being lost. The original code (table based) works properly. It is a simple table declared on the .ascx side:

```
<asp:WizardStep ID="childInformationStep" runat="server" Title="">
    <%-- Some more stuff...--%>
    <asp:Table cellpadding="2" class="annualSurveyTable" cellspacing="0" border="0" ID="tblChildInfo" runat="server">
    </asp:Table>
<asp:WizardStep>
```

On the c# side, during Page_Load, a method is called to cycle through all the children of a family and dynamically build rows with pre-populated input cells for each child's First/Last Name, B-day, gender and grade. It looks like this:

```
private void AddChildEdit(Person child, int index)
    {
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        TableCell cell = new TableCell();
        row.ID = "trChildFirstName_" + index;
        cell.ID = "tcChildFirstName_" + index;
        cell.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Middle;
        cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
        cell.Wrap = false;
        cell.CssClass = "registrationLabel";
        cell.Text = "Child's First Name";
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
        cell = new TableCell();
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.ID = "tbChildFirstName_" + index;
        tb.Text = child.FirstName;
        tb.Enabled = false;
        cell.Controls.Add(tb);
        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        tblChildInfo.Rows.AddAt(tblChildInfo.Rows.Count, row);

        // snip (more of same for last name)

        row = new TableRow();
        cell = new TableCell();
        row.ID = "trChildBirthday_" + index;
        cell.ID = "tcChildBirthday_" + index;
        cell.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Middle;
        cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
        cell.Wrap = false;
        cell.CssClass = "registrationLabel Birthday";
        cell.Text = "Child's Birth Date";
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
        cell = new TableCell();
        DateTextBox dtb = new DateTextBox();
        dtb.ID = "tbChildBirthday_" + index;
        dtb.CssClass = "registrationItem Birthday";
        if (child.BirthDate != DateTime.MinValue && child.BirthDate != DateTime.Parse("1/1/1900"))
            dtb.Text = child.BirthDate.ToShortDateString();
        cell.Controls.Add(dtb);
        row.Cells.Add(cell);

        tblChildInfo.Rows.AddAt(tblChildInfo.Rows.Count, row);

        row = new TableRow();
        cell = new TableCell();
        row.ID = "trChildGender_" + index;
        cell.ID = "tcChildGender_" + index;
        cell.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Middle;
        cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
        cell.Wrap = false;
        cell.CssClass = "registrationLabel";
        cell.Text = "Child's Gender";
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
        cell = new TableCell();
        DropDownList ddlGender = new DropDownList();
        ListItem l = new ListItem("", "", true);
        l.Selected = true;
        ddlGender.Items.Add(l);
        l = new ListItem("Male", "0", true);
        ddlGender.Items.Add(l);
        l = new ListItem("Female", "1", true);
        ddlGender.Items.Add(l);
        ddlGender.ID = "ddlChildGender_" + index;

        // snip (there is one more row added for grade
    }
```

And the save method looks like it cycles through the table looking for the inputs related to the children it is looping through, and pulling in the text value, which should include any changes the user has made. It works as desired, and looks like this (BTW, I didn't write it, it looks like it could be cleaned up quite a bit :D)

```
private void SaveChildValues()
    {
        string userID = CurrentUser.Identity.Name + " - Annual Survey";
        if (userID == " - Annual Survey")
            userID = "Annual Survey";
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Person child in childrenList)
        {
            TableCell selectedCell = null;
            foreach (TableRow row in tblChildInfo.Rows)
            {
                if (row.ID == "trChildBirthday_" + i)
                {
                    foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
                    {
                        if (cell.ID == "tcChildBirthday_" + i)
                        {
                            selectedCell = cell;

                            DateTextBox box = (DateTextBox)selectedCell.FindControl("tbChildBirthday_" + i);
                            if (box.Text.Trim() != string.Empty)
                                try { child.BirthDate = DateTime.Parse(box.Text); }
                                catch { }
                            i++;
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

        i = 0;
        foreach (Person child in childrenList)
        {
            TableCell selectedCell = null;
            foreach (TableRow row in tblChildInfo.Rows)
            {
                if (row.ID == "trChildGender_" + i)
                {
                    foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
                    {
                        if (cell.ID == "tcChildGender_" + i)
                        {
                            selectedCell = cell;
                            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)selectedCell.FindControl("ddlChildGender_" + i);
                            if (ddl.SelectedValue != string.Empty)
                                try { child.Gender = (Gender)Enum.Parse(typeof(Gender), ddl.SelectedValue); }
                                catch { }
                            i++;
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

        i = 0;
        foreach (Person child in childrenList)
        {
            TableCell selectedCell = null;
            foreach (TableRow row in tblChildInfo.Rows)
            {
                if (row.ID == "trChildGrade_" + i)
                {
                    foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
                    {
                        if (cell.ID == "tcChildGrade_" + i)
                        {
                            selectedCell = cell;
                            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)selectedCell.FindControl("ddlChildGrade_" + i);
                            if (ddl.SelectedValue != string.Empty)
                                try { child.GraduationDate = Person.CalculateGraduationYear(Int32.Parse(ddl.SelectedValue), CurrentOrganization.GradePromotionDate); }
                                catch { }
                            i++;
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Now, here are the changes that I have made to that section. The page loads, and runs through all the motions, yet when the save happens, it is pulling in the original DB value from the child record again instead of the user's input. I simply changed the table to an ASP Panel in the .ascx file:

```
<asp:WizardStep ID="childInformationStep" runat="server" Title="">
    <%-- Some more stuff...--%>
    <asp:Panel ID="tblChildInfo" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
    </asp:Panel>
<asp:WizardStep>
```

I have changed the dynamic row creation to dynamic divs, laid out for bootstrap 3:

```
private void AddChildEdit(Person child, int index)
    {
        Panel childRow = new Panel();
        childRow.ID = "ChildRow_" + index;
        childRow.CssClass = "form-horizontal";
        LiteralControl childTitle = new LiteralControl();
        childTitle.Text = string.Format("<h4>Child {0}:</h4>", (index + 1).ToString());
        childRow.Controls.Add(childTitle);
        Panel formGroup = new Panel();
        formGroup.ID = "trChildFirstName_" + index;
        formGroup.CssClass = "form-group";
        childRow.Controls.Add(formGroup);
        Panel inputContainer = new Panel();
        inputContainer.CssClass = "col-sm-8";
        formGroup.Controls.Add(inputContainer);

        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.ID = "tbChildFirstName_" + index;
        tb.Text = child.FirstName;
        tb.Enabled = false;
        inputContainer.Controls.Add(tb);

        Label inputLabel = new Label();
        inputLabel.ID = "tcChildFirstName_" + index;
        inputLabel.CssClass = "col-sm-3 control-label registrationLabel";
        inputLabel.Text = "First Name";
        inputLabel.AssociatedControlID = tb.ID;
        formGroup.Controls.AddAt(0, inputLabel);

        tblChildInfo.Controls.Add(childRow);

        // snip (more code for adding Last Name row

        formGroup = new Panel();
        formGroup.ID = "trChildBirthday_" + index;
        formGroup.CssClass = "form-group";

        inputContainer = new Panel();
        inputContainer.ID = "tcChildBirthday_" + index;
        inputContainer.CssClass = "col-sm-8";
        formGroup.Controls.Add(inputContainer);

        TextBox dtb = new TextBox();
        dtb.ID = "tbChildBirthday_" + index;
        dtb.CssClass = "form-control survey-control date-mask registrationItem";
        dtb.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "MM/DD/YYYY");
        if (child.BirthDate != DateTime.MinValue && child.BirthDate != DateTime.Parse("1/1/1900"))
            dtb.Text = child.BirthDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        inputContainer.Controls.Add(dtb);

        inputLabel = new Label();
        inputLabel.CssClass = "col-sm-3 control-label";
        inputLabel.Text = "BirthDate";
        inputLabel.AssociatedControlID = dtb.ID;
        formGroup.Controls.AddAt(0, inputLabel);

        childRow.Controls.Add(formGroup);

        // snip (more of the same, adding two more rows for gender and grade)
    }
```

And I simplified the save method to:

```
private void SaveChildValues()
    {
        string userID = CurrentUser.Identity.Name + " - Annual Survey";
        if (userID == " - Annual Survey")
            userID = "Annual Survey";
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Person child in childrenList)
        {
            try
            {
                TextBox box = (TextBox)tblChildInfo.FindControl("tbChildBirthday_" + i);
                if (box.Text.Trim() != string.Empty)
                    child.BirthDate = DateTime.Parse(box.Text);
            }
            catch { }
            try
            {
                DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)tblChildInfo.FindControl("ddlChildGender_" + i);  
                if (ddl.SelectedValue != string.Empty)
                    child.Gender = (Gender)Enum.Parse(typeof(Gender), ddl.SelectedValue);
            }
            catch {}
            try
            {
                DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)tblChildInfo.FindControl("ddlChildGrade_" + i);
                if (ddl.SelectedValue != string.Empty)
                    child.GraduationDate = Person.CalculateGraduationYear(Int32.Parse(ddl.SelectedValue), CurrentOrganization.GradePromotionDate);
            }
            catch { }
            i++;
        }
```

As far as I understand it, my code does not change any fundamental behavior, other than it is using div elements to build out the dynamic content rather then adding rows to a table. What am I missing that is causing my updated code to lose the users' input?

NOTE: this is step two, where the information is rendered, captured for the child info. The save method is not executed until step 4, so the input data should be persisting through two more steps, and remain in tact. I have tried using debugger, but can never see the users input. I don't know if I am looking for it at the wrong breakpoints, but I can't seem to find where the user input is coming back with the post, and when it SHOULD be getting written to the inputs. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try moving the dynamic creation of the fields into the Page_Init section rather than the Page_Load.

Comment: That did it! It doesn't explain why the old code (with tables) worked in Page_Load, and mine did not, but I don't really care at this point. Thanks, rclstl!

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that you're creating the DIVs as Panels rather than creating a LiteralControl or using HtmlGenericControl to create the DIV.